# Кнопки увеличиваются не в ту сторону.

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда кнопки стоят в один ряд, они увеличиваются вниз, мне нужно чтобы их увеличение происходило вверх, как исправить ошибку?
Разметку прикрепляю ниже:

```css
div.buttonsfooter {
  width: 350px;
  height: 45px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnnDv.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-left: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div.buttonsfooter:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnnDv.png);
  margin-top: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

a.buttontext {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 28.5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerbutton">
  <div class="buttonsfooter"><a class="buttontext">Калькулятор металла</a></div>
  <div class="buttonsfooter"><a class="buttontext2">ГОСТы и ТУ</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` по-умолчанию имеют `vertical-align: baseline;` , стоит выровнять  `vertical-align: top;` и обе кнопки вверх начинают увеличиваться:

```css
div.buttonsfooter {
  width: 350px;
  height: 45px;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/333/fff);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-left: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

div.buttonsfooter:hover {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ccc/fff);
  margin-top: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

a.buttontext {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.000em;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 28.5%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footerbutton">
  <div class="buttonsfooter">
      <a href="#" class="buttontext">Калькулятор металла</a>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonsfooter">
      <a href="#" class="buttontext">ГОСТы и ТУ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```